# Cross Browser SVG Animation effects in Birds Fly

Tags: css, animation, svg

I am trying to figure out birds `SVG` animation, its animate body like birds, but flap distance is too much!

*Here is the code*

```css
.st0 {
  fill: #242427;
}


@keyframes flyb {
    0%, 100% {
   transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    50% {
    transform: translateY(1.7px);
    }
   }  

@keyframes flap-front {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flap-rear {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flap-front-2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-80deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flap-rear-2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-100deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fly {
  0%,
  100% {
    -WebKit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -Webkit-transform: translateY(1.9px);
  }
}

.fly-group {
  animation: fly 2s ease-in infinite;
  perspective: -1000px;
}

#Layer_35 {
  animation: flyb 2s ease-in infinite;
  perspective: -1000px;
}

#Layer_31,
#Layer_30,
#Layer_33,
#Layer_34,
#Layer_37,
#Layer_36,
#Layer_39,
#Layer_40,
#Layer_42,
#Layer_43,
#Layer_45,
#Layer_46,
#Layer_49,
#Layer_48 {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#Layer_8,
#Layer_10,
#Layer_18,
#Layer_19,
#Layer_24,
#Layer_25,
#Layer_27,
#Layer_28,
#Layer_2,
#Layer_3,
#Layer_7,
#Layer_6,
#Layer_21,
#Layer_22 {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

#Layer_2,
#Layer_3,
#Layer_31,
#Layer_30,
#Layer_33,
#Layer_34,
#Layer_7,
#Layer_6,
#Layer_8,
#Layer_10,
#Layer_18,
#Layer_19,
#Layer_24,
#Layer_25,
#Layer_27,
#Layer_28,
#Layer_42,
#Layer_43,
#Layer_49,
#Layer_48,
#Layer_37,
#Layer_36,
#Layer_39,
#Layer_40 {
  animation: flap-rear-2 2s ease-in infinite;
  perspective: -1000px;
}

#Layer_12,
#Layer_13,
#Layer_15,
#Layer_16,
#Layer_18,
#Layer_19 {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

#Layer_12,
#Layer_15,
#Layer_21,
#Layer_45 {
  animation: flap-front 2s ease-in infinite;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

#Layer_13,
#Layer_1,
#Layer_22,
#Layer_46 {
  animation: flap-rear 2s ease-in infinite;
  perspective: -1000px;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-32.8 416.3 786.4 155.1" style="enable-background:new -32.8 416.3 786.4 155.1;" xml:space="preserve">


<g id="Layer_1">
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_3">
  <g id="Layer_3_1_">
   <path id="XMLID_4_" class="st0" d="M-24.3,421.2c-0.1-0.6-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.6c-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.9-0.8-1.3c0.3,0-1-0.9-2.3-1.4
    c-0.6-0.3-0.3,0.5,0.1,1c0.2,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.7,0.5c0.6,1.1,1.5,1.9,2.5,2.5C-24.6,421-24.5,421.1-24.3,421.2z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_4">
  <g id="Layer_1_18_">
   <path id="XMLID_95_" class="st0" d="M-25.6,418.3c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,0.9-0.1c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.8-0.5c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0
    c-1.3,0-2.5-0.3-3.8-0.8c-0.8-0.4-2.3-0.9-2.7-0.3c-0.1,0-0.5,0-0.5,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1
    c1,0.1,1.3,1.6,3,1.6C-27.2,418.4-26.4,418.4-25.6,418.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_2">
  <g id="Layer_2_1_">
   <path id="XMLID_3_" class="st0" d="M-28.9,417.1c0,0-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1c-0.3,0-1,0.2-1.3,0.4c-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.4-0.8,0.6
    c-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.8-0.9,1.2c-0.3,0.8-0.5,1.7-0.3,2.5c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.2-0.7,0.5-1.2,0.8-1.8c0.4-0.5,0.8-0.8,1.1-1.3c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.5-0.5c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3
    c0.4-0.2,0.7-0.3,1-0.4c0.3-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.2-0.7C-28.6,417.2-28.7,417.1-28.9,417.1z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_7">
  <g id="Layer_3_17_">
   <path id="XMLID_93_" class="st0" d="M106.6,555.9c-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.3-1.2c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.7-0.6-1c0.2,0-0.8-0.6-1.6-1
    c-0.4-0.2-0.2,0.4,0.1,0.8c0.1,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.4c0.4,0.8,1.1,1.4,1.8,1.8C106.4,555.7,106.5,555.8,106.6,555.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_5">
  <g id="Layer_1_2_">
   <path id="XMLID_5_" class="st0" d="M105.6,553.7c0.2,0,0.5-0.1,0.7-0.1c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.6-0.3c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0
    c-1,0-1.8-0.2-2.7-0.6c-0.6-0.3-1.7-0.6-2-0.2c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.3,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c0.7,0.1,0.9,1.1,2.2,1.1
    C104.5,553.8,105,553.8,105.6,553.7z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_6">
  <g id="Layer_2_17_">
   <path id="XMLID_91_" class="st0" d="M103.3,552.9c0,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1c-0.2,0-0.7,0.1-0.9,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.4
    c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.5-0.7,0.9c-0.2,0.6-0.3,1.2-0.2,1.8c0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4c0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.1-0.5,0.3-0.9,0.6-1.3c0.3-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.8-1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2
    c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.8-0.3c0.2-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.5C103.5,553,103.4,552.9,103.3,552.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_8">
  <g id="Layer_2_3_">
   <path id="XMLID_7_" class="st0" d="M351.2,476.9c0,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1c-0.2,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.5,0.4
    c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.5-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.5-0.3,1.1-0.2,1.6c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4c0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.1-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.5-1.2c0.2-0.3,0.5-0.5,0.7-0.9c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2
    c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.7-0.2c0.2-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5C351.4,476.9,351.3,476.9,351.2,476.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_10">
  <g id="Layer_3_16_">
   <path id="XMLID_89_" class="st0" d="M354.2,479.5c-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.3-1c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.5-0.9c0.2,0-0.7-0.6-1.5-0.9
    c-0.4-0.2-0.2,0.3,0.1,0.7c0.1,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.4,0.3c0.4,0.7,1,1.2,1.6,1.6C354,479.4,354.1,479.5,354.2,479.5z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_9">
  <g id="Layer_1_3_">
   <path id="XMLID_8_" class="st0" d="M353.4,477.6c0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.6-0.1c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.5-0.3c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0
    c-0.9,0-1.6-0.2-2.5-0.5c-0.5-0.2-1.5-0.6-1.8-0.2c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.3,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c0.6,0.1,0.8,1,1.9,1
    C352.3,477.7,352.8,477.7,353.4,477.6z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_11">
  <g id="Layer_1_15_">
   <path id="XMLID_87_" class="st0" d="M321.6,513.2c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.1c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9-0.5c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0
    c-1.4,0-2.7-0.3-4-0.9c-0.9-0.4-2.4-0.9-2.9-0.3c-0.1,0-0.5,0-0.5,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1
    c1,0.1,1.3,1.7,3.2,1.7C319.9,513.3,320.7,513.3,321.6,513.2z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_13">
  <g id="Layer_3_4_">
   <path id="XMLID_11_" class="st0" d="M323,516.3c-0.1-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.5-1.7c-0.2-0.5-0.5-1-0.9-1.4c0.3,0-1.1-0.9-2.4-1.5
    c-0.6-0.3-0.3,0.5,0.1,1.1c0.2,0.3,0.7,0.5,0.7,0.6c0.6,1.2,1.6,2,2.7,2.7C322.7,516.1,322.8,516.2,323,516.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_12">
  <g id="Layer_2_15_">
   <path id="XMLID_85_" class="st0" d="M318.1,512c0,0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.1c-0.3,0-1,0.2-1.3,0.5c-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.4-0.9,0.6
    c-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.8-1,1.3c-0.3,0.9-0.5,1.8-0.3,2.7c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.2-0.7,0.5-1.3,0.9-1.9c0.4-0.5,0.8-0.9,1.2-1.4c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.5-0.5c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3
    c0.4-0.2,0.7-0.3,1.1-0.4c0.3-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.2-0.8C318.4,512,318.3,512,318.1,512z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_14">
  <g id="Layer_1_5_">
   <path id="XMLID_15_" class="st0" d="M361.7,446.1c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3,0c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.1c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.2
    c-0.2-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.8-0.1c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0.3,0,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.4C361.3,446.2,361.5,446.2,361.7,446.1
    z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_16">
  <g id="Layer_3_14_">
   <path id="XMLID_83_" class="st0" d="M362.1,446.9c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4c0.1,0-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4
    c-0.2-0.1-0.1,0.1,0,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.1C361.4,446.5,361.7,446.7,362.1,446.9C362,446.9,362,446.9,362.1,446.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_15">
  <g id="Layer_2_5_">
   <path id="XMLID_13_" class="st0" d="M360.8,445.8c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.3,0.1c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.2
    c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.7c0,0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0,0,0,0,0c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5
    c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1
    C361,446,360.9,445.9,360.8,445.8C360.9,445.8,360.8,445.8,360.8,445.8z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_17">
  <g id="Layer_1_13_">
   <path id="XMLID_81_" class="st0" d="M379.6,526.9c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.9-0.1c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.8-0.4c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0
    c-1.2,0-2.3-0.3-3.5-0.8c-0.8-0.3-2.1-0.8-2.5-0.3c-0.1,0-0.4,0-0.4,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1
    c0.9,0.1,1.2,1.4,2.8,1.4C378.2,527.1,378.9,527.1,379.6,526.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_18">
  <g id="Layer_2_6_">
   <path id="XMLID_16_" class="st0" d="M376.6,525.9c0,0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.1c-0.3,0-0.9,0.2-1.2,0.4c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.5
    c-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.9,1.1c-0.3,0.8-0.4,1.6-0.3,2.3c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.2-0.6,0.4-1.1,0.8-1.7c0.3-0.4,0.7-0.8,1-1.2c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3
    c0.3-0.2,0.6-0.3,1-0.3c0.3-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.2-0.7C376.9,526,376.8,525.9,376.6,525.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_19">
  <g id="Layer_3_13_">
   <path id="XMLID_79_" class="st0" d="M380.9,529.6c-0.1-0.5-0.3-1-0.4-1.5c-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.8-1.2c0.3,0-1-0.8-2.1-1.3
    c-0.5-0.2-0.3,0.5,0.1,1c0.2,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.6,0.5c0.5,1,1.4,1.7,2.3,2.3C380.6,529.5,380.7,529.5,380.9,529.6z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_20">
  <g id="Layer_1_7_">
   <path id="XMLID_21_" class="st0" d="M450.1,545.2c0.2,0,0.5-0.1,0.8-0.1c0.2-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.7-0.4c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0
    c-1.1,0-2.1-0.2-3.1-0.7c-0.7-0.3-1.9-0.7-2.2-0.2c-0.1,0-0.4,0-0.4,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1
    c0.8,0.1,1,1.3,2.4,1.3C448.8,545.3,449.4,545.3,450.1,545.2z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_22">
  <g id="Layer_3_12_">
   <path id="XMLID_77_" class="st0" d="M451.2,547.6c-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.4-1.3c-0.1-0.4-0.4-0.8-0.7-1.1c0.2,0-0.8-0.7-1.9-1.2
    c-0.5-0.2-0.3,0.4,0.1,0.9c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.5,0.4c0.5,0.9,1.2,1.5,2.1,2.1C451,547.4,451,547.5,451.2,547.6z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_21">
  <g id="Layer_2_7_">
   <path id="XMLID_20_" class="st0" d="M447.4,544.3c0,0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1c-0.3,0-0.8,0.1-1,0.4c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.3-0.7,0.5
    c-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.6-0.8,1c-0.2,0.7-0.4,1.4-0.2,2.1c0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5c0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.1-0.5,0.4-1,0.7-1.5c0.3-0.4,0.6-0.7,0.9-1.1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2
    c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.8-0.3c0.3-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.6C447.7,544.3,447.6,544.3,447.4,544.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g></g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_23">
  <g id="Layer_1_11_">
   <path id="XMLID_75_" class="st0" d="M516.9,477.5c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.1c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9-0.5c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0
    c-1.4,0-2.7-0.3-4-0.9c-0.9-0.4-2.4-0.9-2.9-0.3c-0.1,0-0.5,0-0.5,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1
    c1,0.1,1.3,1.7,3.2,1.7C515.2,477.7,515.9,477.7,516.9,477.5z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_25">
  <g id="Layer_3_8_">
   <path id="XMLID_23_" class="st0" d="M518.2,480.6c-0.1-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.5-1.7c-0.2-0.5-0.5-1-0.9-1.4c0.3,0-1.1-0.9-2.4-1.5
    c-0.6-0.3-0.3,0.5,0.1,1.1c0.2,0.3,0.7,0.5,0.7,0.6c0.6,1.2,1.6,2,2.7,2.7C517.9,480.4,518,480.5,518.2,480.6z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_24">
  <g id="Layer_2_11_">
   <path id="XMLID_73_" class="st0" d="M513.4,476.3c0,0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.1c-0.3,0-1,0.2-1.3,0.5c-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.4-0.9,0.6
    c-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.8-1,1.3c-0.3,0.9-0.5,1.8-0.3,2.7c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.2-0.7,0.5-1.3,0.9-1.9c0.4-0.5,0.8-0.9,1.2-1.4c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.5-0.5c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3
    c0.4-0.2,0.7-0.3,1.1-0.4c0.3-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.2-0.8C513.6,476.4,513.5,476.3,513.4,476.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_26">
  <g id="Layer_1_9_">
   <path id="XMLID_27_" class="st0" d="M588,567.3c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.9-0.1c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.8-0.4c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0
    c-1.2,0-2.4-0.3-3.5-0.8c-0.8-0.4-2.1-0.8-2.6-0.3c-0.1,0-0.4,0-0.4,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1
    c0.9,0.1,1.2,1.5,2.8,1.5C586.5,567.5,587.2,567.5,588,567.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_28">
  <g id="Layer_3_10_">
   <path id="XMLID_71_" class="st0" d="M589.2,570.1c-0.1-0.5-0.3-1.1-0.4-1.5c-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.8-1.2c0.3,0-1-0.8-2.1-1.3
    c-0.5-0.2-0.3,0.5,0.1,1c0.2,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.6,0.5c0.5,1.1,1.4,1.8,2.4,2.4C589,569.9,589.1,570,589.2,570.1z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_27">
  <g id="Layer_2_9_">
   <path id="XMLID_25_" class="st0" d="M584.9,566.3c0,0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.1c-0.3,0-0.9,0.2-1.2,0.4c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.4-0.8,0.5
    c-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.9,1.1c-0.3,0.8-0.4,1.6-0.3,2.4c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.5c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.2-0.6,0.4-1.1,0.8-1.7c0.4-0.4,0.7-0.8,1.1-1.2c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.4-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3
    c0.4-0.2,0.6-0.3,1-0.4c0.3-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.2-0.7C585.2,566.3,585.1,566.3,584.9,566.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_29">
  <path id="XMLID_69_" class="st0" d="M49.6,432.2c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.4c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0
   c0.4-0.1,0.7,0,1,0.1c0.6,0.4,1.2,0.4,1.9,0.3c0.4-0.1,0.8-0.3,1.1-0.6c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.1,1-0.3
   c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.5c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1c-0.4,0-0.5-0.7-2.4-0.3
   C49.7,431.9,49.7,432.2,49.6,432.2z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_31">
  <path id="XMLID_29_" class="st0" d="M51.6,432.5c0.5,0.1,1.6-0.5,1.6-0.5c0,0-0.2-0.4-0.1-0.6c0-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.6
   c0.2-0.3,0.6-0.6,1-0.9c0.7-0.4,1.2-0.9,1.6-1.5c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.4c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1
   c-0.6,0.6-1.3,1.1-2.1,1.5c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.3c-0.6,0.3-1.1,0.8-1.4,1.5
   C51.2,432,51.5,432.5,51.6,432.5z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_30">
  <path id="XMLID_67_" class="st0" d="M46.2,431.8c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.3,1,0.2c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.9-0.1
   c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.1,1.1,0c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0c-0.1,0.1,1.2,0.4,1.5,0.6c0.3-0.4,0.1-1,0-1c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.9-0.2
   c-0.3-0.3-0.7-0.3-1-0.1c-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.2-1,0.4c-0.6,0.2-1.1,0.2-1.7,0.1C46.3,431.8,46.3,431.8,46.2,431.8z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_32">
  <path id="XMLID_33_" class="st0" d="M63.9,451c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.9,0.1c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.1
   c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.4,1.1,0.7c0.4,0.7,1.2,1.1,2,1.3c0.5,0.1,1,0,1.5-0.1c0.1-0.1,0.2,0,0.3,0c0.4,0.1,0.9,0.3,1.3,0.2
   c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9-0.2c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.1c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.7-0.2c-0.4-0.2-0.2-1.1-2.6-1.7
   C64.2,450.7,64,450.9,63.9,451z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_34">
  <path id="XMLID_65_" class="st0" d="M66,452.3c0.5,0.3,2.1,0.3,2.1,0.3c0,0,0-0.6,0.1-0.7c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.6-0.5
   c0.5-0.2,1-0.4,1.6-0.5c1-0.1,1.8-0.4,2.7-0.9c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5-0.3c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0
   c-1.1,0.3-2.1,0.5-3.1,0.5c-0.3,0-0.7,0-0.9,0c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9,0c-0.9,0-1.7,0.3-2.4,1C65.9,451.5,65.9,452.3,66,452.3z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_33">
  <path id="XMLID_31_" class="st0" d="M60.3,448.7c-0.1,0.2,0,0.3,0.1,0.4c0.3,0.4,0.6,0.7,1,0.8c0.3,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.1,0.4
   c0.4,0.1,0.9,0.3,1.3,0.6c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2c-0.1,0.1,1.1,1.1,1.4,1.4c0.6-0.3,0.7-1.1,0.6-1.1c-0.3-0.1-0.8-0.2-0.9-0.7
   c-0.2-0.6-0.6-0.7-1.1-0.7c-0.5,0-0.8-0.1-1.3-0.1c-0.7-0.1-1.3-0.4-1.9-0.8C60.4,448.7,60.4,448.7,60.3,448.7z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_35">
  <path id="XMLID_63_" class="st0" d="M108.9,520.7c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.5c-0.3,0-0.7,0.1-1,0.5c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0
   c0.6,0,1.1,0.1,1.6,0.4c0.8,0.7,1.8,0.9,2.8,0.8c0.7-0.1,1.2-0.4,1.8-0.7c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1c0.6,0,1.1,0,1.6-0.2
   c0.3-0.1,0.7-0.2,1-0.6c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c-0.3,0-0.7,0.1-0.9,0.1c-0.3,0-0.7,0-0.9,0c-0.6-0.1-0.7-1.2-3.7-1
   C109.2,520.2,109,520.6,108.9,520.7z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_37">
  <path id="XMLID_35_" class="st0" d="M111.9,521.4c0.7,0.2,2.6-0.5,2.6-0.5c0,0-0.2-0.7-0.1-0.9c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.8
   c0.5-0.5,1-0.8,1.7-1.2c1.1-0.5,2-1.2,2.8-2.1c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.6c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1
   c-1.1,0.8-2.2,1.4-3.5,1.9c-0.3,0.1-0.8,0.2-1.1,0.4c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.2-1,0.4c-1,0.4-1.9,1-2.5,2.1
   C111.4,520.5,111.8,521.4,111.9,521.4z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_36">
  <path id="XMLID_61_" class="st0" d="M103.7,519.4c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5c0.5,0.3,0.9,0.6,1.5,0.6c0.5,0,1,0,1.5,0
   c0.6,0,1.1,0,1.7,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1c-0.1,0.1,1.7,0.8,2.2,1.2c0.5-0.6,0.3-1.6,0.2-1.6c-0.5,0-1,0-1.4-0.4
   c-0.5-0.6-1-0.6-1.6-0.4s-1,0.2-1.6,0.4c-0.9,0.1-1.7,0-2.6-0.2C103.8,519.4,103.8,519.4,103.7,519.4z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_38">
  <path id="XMLID_39_" class="st0" d="M223.2,492.5c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.4c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.4c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0
   c0.5,0,0.9,0.1,1.3,0.4c0.7,0.6,1.5,0.7,2.4,0.6c0.6-0.1,1-0.3,1.5-0.6c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1c0.5,0,0.9,0,1.3-0.2
   c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.8-0.5c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.1c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.8,0c-0.5-0.1-0.6-1-3.1-0.8
   C223.4,492.1,223.3,492.4,223.2,492.5z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_40">
  <path id="XMLID_59_" class="st0" d="M225.7,493.1c0.6,0.2,2.1-0.4,2.1-0.4c0,0-0.2-0.6-0.1-0.7c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.5-0.7
   c0.4-0.4,0.8-0.7,1.4-0.9c0.9-0.4,1.7-1,2.3-1.7c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.5c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1
   c-0.9,0.7-1.9,1.2-2.9,1.5c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.2-0.9,0.3c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.8,0.3c-0.8,0.3-1.6,0.9-2.1,1.7
   C225.3,492.4,225.6,493.1,225.7,493.1z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_39">
  <path id="XMLID_37_" class="st0" d="M218.9,491.4c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4c0.4,0.3,0.8,0.5,1.2,0.5c0.4,0,0.8,0,1.2,0
   c0.5,0,0.9,0,1.4,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1c-0.1,0.1,1.4,0.7,1.8,1c0.4-0.5,0.3-1.3,0.2-1.3c-0.4,0-0.8,0-1.1-0.4
   c-0.4-0.5-0.8-0.5-1.3-0.4s-0.8,0.2-1.3,0.3c-0.8,0.1-1.4,0-2.2-0.2C219,491.4,219,491.4,218.9,491.4z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
<g id="Layer_41">
 <path id="XMLID_57_" class="st0" d="M414.8,498.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.4c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.9,0.4c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0
  c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.4,0.4c0.7,0.6,1.6,0.8,2.5,0.7c0.6-0.1,1.1-0.3,1.6-0.6c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1c0.5,0,1,0,1.4-0.2
  c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9-0.5c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.1c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.8,0c-0.5-0.1-0.6-1.1-3.3-0.9
  C415,497.9,414.9,498.2,414.8,498.3z"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_43">
 <path id="XMLID_41_" class="st0" d="M417.4,499c0.6,0.2,2.3-0.4,2.3-0.4c0,0-0.2-0.6-0.1-0.8c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.5-0.7
  c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.7,1.5-1c1-0.4,1.8-1,2.5-1.8c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.5c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1
  c-1,0.7-2,1.2-3.1,1.6c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.2-1,0.3c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.9,0.3c-0.9,0.3-1.7,0.9-2.2,1.8C417,498.2,417.3,499,417.4,499z"
  />
</g>
<g id="Layer_42">
 <path id="XMLID_55_" class="st0" d="M410.2,497.2c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4c0.4,0.3,0.8,0.5,1.3,0.5c0.4,0,0.9,0,1.3,0
  c0.5,0,1,0,1.5,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1c-0.1,0.1,1.5,0.8,1.9,1c0.5-0.5,0.3-1.4,0.2-1.4c-0.4,0-0.9,0-1.2-0.4
  c-0.4-0.5-0.9-0.5-1.4-0.4c-0.5,0.1-0.9,0.2-1.4,0.3c-0.8,0.1-1.5,0-2.3-0.2C410.3,497.2,410.3,497.2,410.2,497.2z"/>
</g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_44">
  <path id="XMLID_45_" class="st0" d="M521.9,525.5c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5,0.2c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0
   c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.8,0.2c0.4,0.3,0.9,0.5,1.5,0.4c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.2,0.9-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.8-0.1
   c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.5-0.3c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5,0.1c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.5,0c-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.7-1.9-0.5
   C522,525.2,522,525.4,521.9,525.5z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_46">
  <path id="XMLID_53_" class="st0" d="M523.5,525.9c0.4,0.1,1.3-0.3,1.3-0.3c0,0-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4
   c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.9-0.6c0.6-0.2,1.1-0.6,1.5-1.1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.3c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1
   c-0.6,0.4-1.2,0.7-1.8,1c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.2c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.5,0.2c-0.5,0.2-1,0.5-1.3,1.1
   C523.2,525.4,523.4,525.9,523.5,525.9z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_45">
  <path id="XMLID_43_" class="st0" d="M519.2,524.8c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.3c0.2,0,0.5,0,0.8,0
   c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1c-0.1,0.1,0.9,0.4,1.1,0.6c0.3-0.3,0.2-0.8,0.1-0.8c-0.2,0-0.5,0-0.7-0.2
   c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.2c-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8,0.2c-0.5,0.1-0.9,0-1.4-0.1C519.2,524.8,519.2,524.8,519.2,524.8z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_47">
  <path id="XMLID_51_" class="st0" d="M742.4,510.8c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.3,0.3c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1-1,0c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.1
   c0.5,0.2,0.9,0.5,1.2,0.9c0.4,0.9,1.2,1.4,2.1,1.7c0.6,0.1,1.2,0.2,1.8,0.1c0.1-0.1,0.2,0,0.3,0c0.5,0.2,1,0.4,1.4,0.4
   c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,1.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.2c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.8-0.3c-0.4-0.3-0.1-1.3-2.7-2.2
   C742.7,510.5,742.5,510.8,742.4,510.8z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_49">
  <path id="XMLID_47_" class="st0" d="M744.6,512.6c0.5,0.4,2.3,0.5,2.3,0.5c0,0,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.8c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.8-0.5
   c0.5-0.2,1.1-0.3,1.8-0.3c1.1,0,2.1-0.2,3.1-0.7c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.3c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0
   c-1.2,0.3-2.4,0.4-3.6,0.3c-0.3,0-0.7-0.1-1.1-0.1c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-1-0.1c-1-0.1-2,0.2-2.8,0.8C744.5,511.6,744.5,512.5,744.6,512.6
   z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_48">
  <path id="XMLID_49_" class="st0" d="M738.5,507.8c-0.1,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5c0.3,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1c0.4,0.2,0.9,0.4,1.2,0.5
   c0.5,0.2,1,0.4,1.4,0.8c0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2c-0.1,0.1,1.1,1.3,1.4,1.8c0.7-0.3,0.9-1.2,0.8-1.2c-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.4-1-0.9
   c-0.2-0.6-0.6-0.8-1.2-0.9c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.2-1.5-0.3c-0.8-0.2-1.4-0.6-2.1-1.1C738.6,507.9,738.6,507.9,738.5,507.8z"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

So I try to control flaps with body movement but I couldn't!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.st0 {
  fill: #242427;
}


@keyframes flyb {
    0%, 100% {
   transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    50% {
    transform: translateY(1.7px);
    }
   }  

@keyframes flap-front {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(18deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flap-rear {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(-18deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flap-front-2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flap-rear-2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fly {
  0%,
  100% {
    -WebKit-transform: translateY(1.8px);
  }
  50% {
    -Webkit-transform: translateY(1.9px);
  }
}

.fly-group {
  animation: fly 2s ease-in infinite;
  perspective: -1000px;
}

#Layer_35 {
  animation: flyb 2s ease-in infinite;
  perspective: -1000px;
}

#Layer_31,
#Layer_30,
#Layer_33,
#Layer_34,
#Layer_37,
#Layer_36,
#Layer_39,
#Layer_40,
#Layer_42,
#Layer_43,
#Layer_45,
#Layer_46,
#Layer_49,
#Layer_48 {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#Layer_8,
#Layer_10,
#Layer_18,
#Layer_19,
#Layer_24,
#Layer_25,
#Layer_27,
#Layer_28,
#Layer_2,
#Layer_3,
#Layer_7,
#Layer_6,
#Layer_21,
#Layer_22 {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

#Layer_2,
#Layer_3,
#Layer_31,
#Layer_30,
#Layer_33,
#Layer_34,
#Layer_7,
#Layer_6,
#Layer_8,
#Layer_10,
#Layer_18,
#Layer_19,
#Layer_24,
#Layer_25,
#Layer_27,
#Layer_28,
#Layer_42,
#Layer_43,
#Layer_49,
#Layer_48,
#Layer_37,
#Layer_36,
#Layer_39,
#Layer_40 {
  animation: flap-rear-2 2s ease-in infinite;
  perspective: -1000px;
}

#Layer_12,
#Layer_13,
#Layer_15,
#Layer_16,
#Layer_18,
#Layer_19 {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

#Layer_12,
#Layer_15,
#Layer_21,
#Layer_45 {
  animation: flap-front 2s ease-in infinite;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

#Layer_13,
#Layer_1,
#Layer_22,
#Layer_46 {
  animation: flap-rear 2s ease-in infinite;
  perspective: -1000px;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-32.8 416.3 786.4 155.1" style="enable-background:new -32.8 416.3 786.4 155.1;" xml:space="preserve">


<g id="Layer_1">
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_3">
  <g id="Layer_3_1_">
   <path id="XMLID_4_" class="st0" d="M-24.3,421.2c-0.1-0.6-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.6c-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.9-0.8-1.3c0.3,0-1-0.9-2.3-1.4
    c-0.6-0.3-0.3,0.5,0.1,1c0.2,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.7,0.5c0.6,1.1,1.5,1.9,2.5,2.5C-24.6,421-24.5,421.1-24.3,421.2z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_4">
  <g id="Layer_1_18_">
   <path id="XMLID_95_" class="st0" d="M-25.6,418.3c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,0.9-0.1c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.8-0.5c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0
    c-1.3,0-2.5-0.3-3.8-0.8c-0.8-0.4-2.3-0.9-2.7-0.3c-0.1,0-0.5,0-0.5,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1
    c1,0.1,1.3,1.6,3,1.6C-27.2,418.4-26.4,418.4-25.6,418.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_2">
  <g id="Layer_2_1_">
   <path id="XMLID_3_" class="st0" d="M-28.9,417.1c0,0-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1c-0.3,0-1,0.2-1.3,0.4c-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.4-0.8,0.6
    c-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.8-0.9,1.2c-0.3,0.8-0.5,1.7-0.3,2.5c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.2-0.7,0.5-1.2,0.8-1.8c0.4-0.5,0.8-0.8,1.1-1.3c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.5-0.5c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3
    c0.4-0.2,0.7-0.3,1-0.4c0.3-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.2-0.7C-28.6,417.2-28.7,417.1-28.9,417.1z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_7">
  <g id="Layer_3_17_">
   <path id="XMLID_93_" class="st0" d="M106.6,555.9c-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.3-1.2c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.7-0.6-1c0.2,0-0.8-0.6-1.6-1
    c-0.4-0.2-0.2,0.4,0.1,0.8c0.1,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.4c0.4,0.8,1.1,1.4,1.8,1.8C106.4,555.7,106.5,555.8,106.6,555.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_5">
  <g id="Layer_1_2_">
   <path id="XMLID_5_" class="st0" d="M105.6,553.7c0.2,0,0.5-0.1,0.7-0.1c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.6-0.3c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0
    c-1,0-1.8-0.2-2.7-0.6c-0.6-0.3-1.7-0.6-2-0.2c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.3,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c0.7,0.1,0.9,1.1,2.2,1.1
    C104.5,553.8,105,553.8,105.6,553.7z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_6">
  <g id="Layer_2_17_">
   <path id="XMLID_91_" class="st0" d="M103.3,552.9c0,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1c-0.2,0-0.7,0.1-0.9,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.4
    c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.5-0.7,0.9c-0.2,0.6-0.3,1.2-0.2,1.8c0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4c0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.1-0.5,0.3-0.9,0.6-1.3c0.3-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.8-1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2
    c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.8-0.3c0.2-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.5C103.5,553,103.4,552.9,103.3,552.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_8">
  <g id="Layer_2_3_">
   <path id="XMLID_7_" class="st0" d="M351.2,476.9c0,0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1c-0.2,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.5,0.4
    c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.5-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.5-0.3,1.1-0.2,1.6c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4c0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.1-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.5-1.2c0.2-0.3,0.5-0.5,0.7-0.9c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2
    c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.7-0.2c0.2-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5C351.4,476.9,351.3,476.9,351.2,476.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_10">
  <g id="Layer_3_16_">
   <path id="XMLID_89_" class="st0" d="M354.2,479.5c-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.3-1c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.5-0.9c0.2,0-0.7-0.6-1.5-0.9
    c-0.4-0.2-0.2,0.3,0.1,0.7c0.1,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.4,0.3c0.4,0.7,1,1.2,1.6,1.6C354,479.4,354.1,479.5,354.2,479.5z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_9">
  <g id="Layer_1_3_">
   <path id="XMLID_8_" class="st0" d="M353.4,477.6c0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.6-0.1c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.5-0.3c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0
    c-0.9,0-1.6-0.2-2.5-0.5c-0.5-0.2-1.5-0.6-1.8-0.2c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.3,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c0.6,0.1,0.8,1,1.9,1
    C352.3,477.7,352.8,477.7,353.4,477.6z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_11">
  <g id="Layer_1_15_">
   <path id="XMLID_87_" class="st0" d="M321.6,513.2c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.1c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9-0.5c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0
    c-1.4,0-2.7-0.3-4-0.9c-0.9-0.4-2.4-0.9-2.9-0.3c-0.1,0-0.5,0-0.5,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1
    c1,0.1,1.3,1.7,3.2,1.7C319.9,513.3,320.7,513.3,321.6,513.2z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_13">
  <g id="Layer_3_4_">
   <path id="XMLID_11_" class="st0" d="M323,516.3c-0.1-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.5-1.7c-0.2-0.5-0.5-1-0.9-1.4c0.3,0-1.1-0.9-2.4-1.5
    c-0.6-0.3-0.3,0.5,0.1,1.1c0.2,0.3,0.7,0.5,0.7,0.6c0.6,1.2,1.6,2,2.7,2.7C322.7,516.1,322.8,516.2,323,516.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_12">
  <g id="Layer_2_15_">
   <path id="XMLID_85_" class="st0" d="M318.1,512c0,0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.1c-0.3,0-1,0.2-1.3,0.5c-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.4-0.9,0.6
    c-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.8-1,1.3c-0.3,0.9-0.5,1.8-0.3,2.7c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.2-0.7,0.5-1.3,0.9-1.9c0.4-0.5,0.8-0.9,1.2-1.4c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.5-0.5c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3
    c0.4-0.2,0.7-0.3,1.1-0.4c0.3-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.2-0.8C318.4,512,318.3,512,318.1,512z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_14">
  <g id="Layer_1_5_">
   <path id="XMLID_15_" class="st0" d="M361.7,446.1c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3,0c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.2-0.1c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.2
    c-0.2-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.8-0.1c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0.3,0,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.4C361.3,446.2,361.5,446.2,361.7,446.1
    z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_16">
  <g id="Layer_3_14_">
   <path id="XMLID_83_" class="st0" d="M362.1,446.9c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4c0.1,0-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4
    c-0.2-0.1-0.1,0.1,0,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.1C361.4,446.5,361.7,446.7,362.1,446.9C362,446.9,362,446.9,362.1,446.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_15">
  <g id="Layer_2_5_">
   <path id="XMLID_13_" class="st0" d="M360.8,445.8c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.3,0.1c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.2
    c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.7c0,0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0,0,0,0,0c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5
    c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1
    C361,446,360.9,445.9,360.8,445.8C360.9,445.8,360.8,445.8,360.8,445.8z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_17">
  <g id="Layer_1_13_">
   <path id="XMLID_81_" class="st0" d="M379.6,526.9c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.9-0.1c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.8-0.4c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0
    c-1.2,0-2.3-0.3-3.5-0.8c-0.8-0.3-2.1-0.8-2.5-0.3c-0.1,0-0.4,0-0.4,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1
    c0.9,0.1,1.2,1.4,2.8,1.4C378.2,527.1,378.9,527.1,379.6,526.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_18">
  <g id="Layer_2_6_">
   <path id="XMLID_16_" class="st0" d="M376.6,525.9c0,0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.1c-0.3,0-0.9,0.2-1.2,0.4c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.5
    c-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.9,1.1c-0.3,0.8-0.4,1.6-0.3,2.3c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.2-0.6,0.4-1.1,0.8-1.7c0.3-0.4,0.7-0.8,1-1.2c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3
    c0.3-0.2,0.6-0.3,1-0.3c0.3-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.2-0.7C376.9,526,376.8,525.9,376.6,525.9z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_19">
  <g id="Layer_3_13_">
   <path id="XMLID_79_" class="st0" d="M380.9,529.6c-0.1-0.5-0.3-1-0.4-1.5c-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.8-1.2c0.3,0-1-0.8-2.1-1.3
    c-0.5-0.2-0.3,0.5,0.1,1c0.2,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.6,0.5c0.5,1,1.4,1.7,2.3,2.3C380.6,529.5,380.7,529.5,380.9,529.6z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_20">
  <g id="Layer_1_7_">
   <path id="XMLID_21_" class="st0" d="M450.1,545.2c0.2,0,0.5-0.1,0.8-0.1c0.2-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.7-0.4c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0
    c-1.1,0-2.1-0.2-3.1-0.7c-0.7-0.3-1.9-0.7-2.2-0.2c-0.1,0-0.4,0-0.4,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1
    c0.8,0.1,1,1.3,2.4,1.3C448.8,545.3,449.4,545.3,450.1,545.2z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_22">
  <g id="Layer_3_12_">
   <path id="XMLID_77_" class="st0" d="M451.2,547.6c-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.4-1.3c-0.1-0.4-0.4-0.8-0.7-1.1c0.2,0-0.8-0.7-1.9-1.2
    c-0.5-0.2-0.3,0.4,0.1,0.9c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.5,0.4c0.5,0.9,1.2,1.5,2.1,2.1C451,547.4,451,547.5,451.2,547.6z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_21">
  <g id="Layer_2_7_">
   <path id="XMLID_20_" class="st0" d="M447.4,544.3c0,0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1c-0.3,0-0.8,0.1-1,0.4c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.3-0.7,0.5
    c-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.6-0.8,1c-0.2,0.7-0.4,1.4-0.2,2.1c0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5c0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.1-0.5,0.4-1,0.7-1.5c0.3-0.4,0.6-0.7,0.9-1.1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2
    c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.8-0.3c0.3-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.6C447.7,544.3,447.6,544.3,447.4,544.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g></g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_23">
  <g id="Layer_1_11_">
   <path id="XMLID_75_" class="st0" d="M516.9,477.5c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.1c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9-0.5c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0
    c-1.4,0-2.7-0.3-4-0.9c-0.9-0.4-2.4-0.9-2.9-0.3c-0.1,0-0.5,0-0.5,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1
    c1,0.1,1.3,1.7,3.2,1.7C515.2,477.7,515.9,477.7,516.9,477.5z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_25">
  <g id="Layer_3_8_">
   <path id="XMLID_23_" class="st0" d="M518.2,480.6c-0.1-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.5-1.7c-0.2-0.5-0.5-1-0.9-1.4c0.3,0-1.1-0.9-2.4-1.5
    c-0.6-0.3-0.3,0.5,0.1,1.1c0.2,0.3,0.7,0.5,0.7,0.6c0.6,1.2,1.6,2,2.7,2.7C517.9,480.4,518,480.5,518.2,480.6z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_24">
  <g id="Layer_2_11_">
   <path id="XMLID_73_" class="st0" d="M513.4,476.3c0,0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.1c-0.3,0-1,0.2-1.3,0.5c-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.4-0.9,0.6
    c-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.8-1,1.3c-0.3,0.9-0.5,1.8-0.3,2.7c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.2-0.7,0.5-1.3,0.9-1.9c0.4-0.5,0.8-0.9,1.2-1.4c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.5-0.5c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3
    c0.4-0.2,0.7-0.3,1.1-0.4c0.3-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.2-0.8C513.6,476.4,513.5,476.3,513.4,476.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_26">
  <g id="Layer_1_9_">
   <path id="XMLID_27_" class="st0" d="M588,567.3c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.9-0.1c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.8-0.4c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0
    c-1.2,0-2.4-0.3-3.5-0.8c-0.8-0.4-2.1-0.8-2.6-0.3c-0.1,0-0.4,0-0.4,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.2,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1
    c0.9,0.1,1.2,1.5,2.8,1.5C586.5,567.5,587.2,567.5,588,567.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_28">
  <g id="Layer_3_10_">
   <path id="XMLID_71_" class="st0" d="M589.2,570.1c-0.1-0.5-0.3-1.1-0.4-1.5c-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.8-1.2c0.3,0-1-0.8-2.1-1.3
    c-0.5-0.2-0.3,0.5,0.1,1c0.2,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.6,0.5c0.5,1.1,1.4,1.8,2.4,2.4C589,569.9,589.1,570,589.2,570.1z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_27">
  <g id="Layer_2_9_">
   <path id="XMLID_25_" class="st0" d="M584.9,566.3c0,0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.1c-0.3,0-0.9,0.2-1.2,0.4c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.4-0.8,0.5
    c-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.9,1.1c-0.3,0.8-0.4,1.6-0.3,2.4c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.5c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1
    c0.2-0.6,0.4-1.1,0.8-1.7c0.4-0.4,0.7-0.8,1.1-1.2c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.4-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3
    c0.4-0.2,0.6-0.3,1-0.4c0.3-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.2-0.7C585.2,566.3,585.1,566.3,584.9,566.3z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_29">
  <path id="XMLID_69_" class="st0" d="M49.6,432.2c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.4c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0
   c0.4-0.1,0.7,0,1,0.1c0.6,0.4,1.2,0.4,1.9,0.3c0.4-0.1,0.8-0.3,1.1-0.6c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.1,1-0.3
   c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.5c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1c-0.4,0-0.5-0.7-2.4-0.3
   C49.7,431.9,49.7,432.2,49.6,432.2z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_31">
  <path id="XMLID_29_" class="st0" d="M51.6,432.5c0.5,0.1,1.6-0.5,1.6-0.5c0,0-0.2-0.4-0.1-0.6c0-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.6
   c0.2-0.3,0.6-0.6,1-0.9c0.7-0.4,1.2-0.9,1.6-1.5c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.4c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1
   c-0.6,0.6-1.3,1.1-2.1,1.5c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.3c-0.6,0.3-1.1,0.8-1.4,1.5
   C51.2,432,51.5,432.5,51.6,432.5z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_30">
  <path id="XMLID_67_" class="st0" d="M46.2,431.8c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.3,1,0.2c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.9-0.1
   c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.1,1.1,0c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0c-0.1,0.1,1.2,0.4,1.5,0.6c0.3-0.4,0.1-1,0-1c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.9-0.2
   c-0.3-0.3-0.7-0.3-1-0.1c-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.2-1,0.4c-0.6,0.2-1.1,0.2-1.7,0.1C46.3,431.8,46.3,431.8,46.2,431.8z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_32">
  <path id="XMLID_33_" class="st0" d="M63.9,451c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.9,0.1c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.1
   c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.4,1.1,0.7c0.4,0.7,1.2,1.1,2,1.3c0.5,0.1,1,0,1.5-0.1c0.1-0.1,0.2,0,0.3,0c0.4,0.1,0.9,0.3,1.3,0.2
   c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9-0.2c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.1c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.7-0.2c-0.4-0.2-0.2-1.1-2.6-1.7
   C64.2,450.7,64,450.9,63.9,451z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_34">
  <path id="XMLID_65_" class="st0" d="M66,452.3c0.5,0.3,2.1,0.3,2.1,0.3c0,0,0-0.6,0.1-0.7c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.6-0.5
   c0.5-0.2,1-0.4,1.6-0.5c1-0.1,1.8-0.4,2.7-0.9c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5-0.3c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0
   c-1.1,0.3-2.1,0.5-3.1,0.5c-0.3,0-0.7,0-0.9,0c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9,0c-0.9,0-1.7,0.3-2.4,1C65.9,451.5,65.9,452.3,66,452.3z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_33">
  <path id="XMLID_31_" class="st0" d="M60.3,448.7c-0.1,0.2,0,0.3,0.1,0.4c0.3,0.4,0.6,0.7,1,0.8c0.3,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.1,0.4
   c0.4,0.1,0.9,0.3,1.3,0.6c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2c-0.1,0.1,1.1,1.1,1.4,1.4c0.6-0.3,0.7-1.1,0.6-1.1c-0.3-0.1-0.8-0.2-0.9-0.7
   c-0.2-0.6-0.6-0.7-1.1-0.7c-0.5,0-0.8-0.1-1.3-0.1c-0.7-0.1-1.3-0.4-1.9-0.8C60.4,448.7,60.4,448.7,60.3,448.7z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_35">
  <path id="XMLID_63_" class="st0" d="M108.9,520.7c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.5c-0.3,0-0.7,0.1-1,0.5c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0
   c0.6,0,1.1,0.1,1.6,0.4c0.8,0.7,1.8,0.9,2.8,0.8c0.7-0.1,1.2-0.4,1.8-0.7c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1c0.6,0,1.1,0,1.6-0.2
   c0.3-0.1,0.7-0.2,1-0.6c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c-0.3,0-0.7,0.1-0.9,0.1c-0.3,0-0.7,0-0.9,0c-0.6-0.1-0.7-1.2-3.7-1
   C109.2,520.2,109,520.6,108.9,520.7z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_37">
  <path id="XMLID_35_" class="st0" d="M111.9,521.4c0.7,0.2,2.6-0.5,2.6-0.5c0,0-0.2-0.7-0.1-0.9c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.8
   c0.5-0.5,1-0.8,1.7-1.2c1.1-0.5,2-1.2,2.8-2.1c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.6c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1
   c-1.1,0.8-2.2,1.4-3.5,1.9c-0.3,0.1-0.8,0.2-1.1,0.4c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.2-1,0.4c-1,0.4-1.9,1-2.5,2.1
   C111.4,520.5,111.8,521.4,111.9,521.4z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_36">
  <path id="XMLID_61_" class="st0" d="M103.7,519.4c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5c0.5,0.3,0.9,0.6,1.5,0.6c0.5,0,1,0,1.5,0
   c0.6,0,1.1,0,1.7,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1c-0.1,0.1,1.7,0.8,2.2,1.2c0.5-0.6,0.3-1.6,0.2-1.6c-0.5,0-1,0-1.4-0.4
   c-0.5-0.6-1-0.6-1.6-0.4s-1,0.2-1.6,0.4c-0.9,0.1-1.7,0-2.6-0.2C103.8,519.4,103.8,519.4,103.7,519.4z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_38">
  <path id="XMLID_39_" class="st0" d="M223.2,492.5c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.4c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.4c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0
   c0.5,0,0.9,0.1,1.3,0.4c0.7,0.6,1.5,0.7,2.4,0.6c0.6-0.1,1-0.3,1.5-0.6c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1c0.5,0,0.9,0,1.3-0.2
   c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.8-0.5c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.1c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.8,0c-0.5-0.1-0.6-1-3.1-0.8
   C223.4,492.1,223.3,492.4,223.2,492.5z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_40">
  <path id="XMLID_59_" class="st0" d="M225.7,493.1c0.6,0.2,2.1-0.4,2.1-0.4c0,0-0.2-0.6-0.1-0.7c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.5-0.7
   c0.4-0.4,0.8-0.7,1.4-0.9c0.9-0.4,1.7-1,2.3-1.7c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.5c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1
   c-0.9,0.7-1.9,1.2-2.9,1.5c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.2-0.9,0.3c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.8,0.3c-0.8,0.3-1.6,0.9-2.1,1.7
   C225.3,492.4,225.6,493.1,225.7,493.1z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_39">
  <path id="XMLID_37_" class="st0" d="M218.9,491.4c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4c0.4,0.3,0.8,0.5,1.2,0.5c0.4,0,0.8,0,1.2,0
   c0.5,0,0.9,0,1.4,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1c-0.1,0.1,1.4,0.7,1.8,1c0.4-0.5,0.3-1.3,0.2-1.3c-0.4,0-0.8,0-1.1-0.4
   c-0.4-0.5-0.8-0.5-1.3-0.4s-0.8,0.2-1.3,0.3c-0.8,0.1-1.4,0-2.2-0.2C219,491.4,219,491.4,218.9,491.4z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
<g id="Layer_41">
 <path id="XMLID_57_" class="st0" d="M414.8,498.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.4c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.9,0.4c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0
  c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.4,0.4c0.7,0.6,1.6,0.8,2.5,0.7c0.6-0.1,1.1-0.3,1.6-0.6c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1c0.5,0,1,0,1.4-0.2
  c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9-0.5c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.1c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.8,0c-0.5-0.1-0.6-1.1-3.3-0.9
  C415,497.9,414.9,498.2,414.8,498.3z"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_43">
 <path id="XMLID_41_" class="st0" d="M417.4,499c0.6,0.2,2.3-0.4,2.3-0.4c0,0-0.2-0.6-0.1-0.8c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.5-0.7
  c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.7,1.5-1c1-0.4,1.8-1,2.5-1.8c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.5c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1
  c-1,0.7-2,1.2-3.1,1.6c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.2-1,0.3c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.9,0.3c-0.9,0.3-1.7,0.9-2.2,1.8C417,498.2,417.3,499,417.4,499z"
  />
</g>
<g id="Layer_42">
 <path id="XMLID_55_" class="st0" d="M410.2,497.2c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4c0.4,0.3,0.8,0.5,1.3,0.5c0.4,0,0.9,0,1.3,0
  c0.5,0,1,0,1.5,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1c-0.1,0.1,1.5,0.8,1.9,1c0.5-0.5,0.3-1.4,0.2-1.4c-0.4,0-0.9,0-1.2-0.4
  c-0.4-0.5-0.9-0.5-1.4-0.4c-0.5,0.1-0.9,0.2-1.4,0.3c-0.8,0.1-1.5,0-2.3-0.2C410.3,497.2,410.3,497.2,410.2,497.2z"/>
</g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_44">
  <path id="XMLID_45_" class="st0" d="M521.9,525.5c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5,0.2c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0
   c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.8,0.2c0.4,0.3,0.9,0.5,1.5,0.4c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.2,0.9-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.8-0.1
   c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.5-0.3c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5,0.1c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.5,0c-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.7-1.9-0.5
   C522,525.2,522,525.4,521.9,525.5z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_46">
  <path id="XMLID_53_" class="st0" d="M523.5,525.9c0.4,0.1,1.3-0.3,1.3-0.3c0,0-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4
   c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.9-0.6c0.6-0.2,1.1-0.6,1.5-1.1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.3c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1
   c-0.6,0.4-1.2,0.7-1.8,1c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.2c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.5,0.2c-0.5,0.2-1,0.5-1.3,1.1
   C523.2,525.4,523.4,525.9,523.5,525.9z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_45">
  <path id="XMLID_43_" class="st0" d="M519.2,524.8c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.3c0.2,0,0.5,0,0.8,0
   c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9,0.1c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1c-0.1,0.1,0.9,0.4,1.1,0.6c0.3-0.3,0.2-0.8,0.1-0.8c-0.2,0-0.5,0-0.7-0.2
   c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.2c-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8,0.2c-0.5,0.1-0.9,0-1.4-0.1C519.2,524.8,519.2,524.8,519.2,524.8z"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g class="fly-group">
 <g id="Layer_47">
  <path id="XMLID_51_" class="st0" d="M742.4,510.8c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.3,0.3c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1-1,0c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.1
   c0.5,0.2,0.9,0.5,1.2,0.9c0.4,0.9,1.2,1.4,2.1,1.7c0.6,0.1,1.2,0.2,1.8,0.1c0.1-0.1,0.2,0,0.3,0c0.5,0.2,1,0.4,1.4,0.4
   c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,1.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.2c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.8-0.3c-0.4-0.3-0.1-1.3-2.7-2.2
   C742.7,510.5,742.5,510.8,742.4,510.8z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_49">
  <path id="XMLID_47_" class="st0" d="M744.6,512.6c0.5,0.4,2.3,0.5,2.3,0.5c0,0,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.8c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.8-0.5
   c0.5-0.2,1.1-0.3,1.8-0.3c1.1,0,2.1-0.2,3.1-0.7c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.3c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0
   c-1.2,0.3-2.4,0.4-3.6,0.3c-0.3,0-0.7-0.1-1.1-0.1c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-1-0.1c-1-0.1-2,0.2-2.8,0.8C744.5,511.6,744.5,512.5,744.6,512.6
   z"/>
 </g>
 <g id="Layer_48">
  <path id="XMLID_49_" class="st0" d="M738.5,507.8c-0.1,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5c0.3,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1c0.4,0.2,0.9,0.4,1.2,0.5
   c0.5,0.2,1,0.4,1.4,0.8c0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2c-0.1,0.1,1.1,1.3,1.4,1.8c0.7-0.3,0.9-1.2,0.8-1.2c-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.4-1-0.9
   c-0.2-0.6-0.6-0.8-1.2-0.9c-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.2-1.5-0.3c-0.8-0.2-1.4-0.6-2.1-1.1C738.6,507.9,738.6,507.9,738.5,507.8z"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you do this something like http://flyec.com.bd/ ? at the bottom section you will find svg  animation...

Comment: will try and will add here.